# multiple array to a single array php

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible in php to change this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image_name] => image1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image_name] => image2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [image_name] => image3

        )

)
```

to this kind of array . in which their index names are same.

```
Array
(
    [image_name1] => image1
    [image_name2] => image2
    [image_name3] => image3 
)
```

Comment: The way you imagined it, is not possible. An array can have a single value for a single key. It cannot contain the `image_name` key multiple times. What would `$array['image_name']` return?

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: You could make `$arary['image_name']` an array of values, but the way you show in your example is not possible.

Comment: `$flattened = array_column($oldArray, 'image_name');` as a quick way of flattening that array for PHP >= 5.5; but you must still have unique keys for the index

Comment: What's wrong with a simple enumerated index? Why do you need an associative index with incrementing numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `foreach` loop like this:

```
// Set a test array.
$test_array = array();
$test_array[] = array('image_name_1' => 'image1');
$test_array[] = array('image_name_2' => 'image2');
$test_array[] = array('image_name_3' => 'image3');

// Roll through the array & set a new array.
$new_array = array();
foreach($test_array as $parent_key => $parent_value) {
  foreach($parent_value as $child_key => $child_value) {
    $new_array[$child_key] = $child_value;
  }
}

// Dump the output for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the final results are:

```
Array
(
    [image_name_1] => image1
    [image_name_2] => image2
    [image_name_3] => image3
)
```